# C++ Tic Tac Toe Game cannot change private members

Tags: c++

I am creating an OOP tic tac toe game. I cannot understand why certain things are not working properly. First of all, I cannot change my gameBoard array by passing in a number for column and another one for row and changing it in that function. Second, the checkWinner function should change the player if there is no one, but it does not seem to do that either. Here is my code:

TicTacToe.h:

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H
#define TICTACTOE_H
using namespace std;

class TicTacToe{
private:
    int gameBoard[3][3];
    int playerTurn = 1;

public:
    TicTacToe();
    void printBoard();
    int printPlayer();
    bool changeBoard(int, int);
    bool checkWinner();

};

#endif
```

TicTacToe.cpp:

```
#include "TicTacToe.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

TicTacToe::TicTacToe(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            gameBoard[i][j] = 0;

        }
    }
}
void TicTacToe::printBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << gameBoard[i][j];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int TicTacToe::printPlayer(){
    return playerTurn;
}

bool TicTacToe::changeBoard(int r, int s){
    if (gameBoard[r][s] == 0){
        gameBoard[r][s] == playerTurn;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool TicTacToe::checkWinner(){
    if (gameBoard[0][0] && gameBoard[1][0] && gameBoard[2][0] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0][1] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][1] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0][2] && gameBoard[1][2] && gameBoard[2][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    /*********************************/
    if (gameBoard[0][0] && gameBoard[0][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[1][0] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[1][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[2][1] && gameBoard[2][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    /*********************************/
    else if (gameBoard[0][0] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0][2] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][0] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }

    /*********************************/
    else{
        if (playerTurn == 1){
            playerTurn == 2;
        }
        else{
            playerTurn == 1;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

TicTacToeApp.cpp:

```
#include "TicTacToe.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    const int boardNumber = 3;
        int selection;
        int row;
        int col;
        TicTacToe gameBoard;
        do{
        cout << "Welcome to TicTacToe!" << endl
            << "1) Play Game" << endl
            << "2) Quit" << endl;
        cin >> selection;

            if (selection == 1){
                do{
                    gameBoard.printBoard();
                    cout << "Player #" << gameBoard.printPlayer() << ":" << endl
                        << "Row: ";
                    cin >> row;
                    row = row - 1;
                    cout << "\n";
                    cout << "Column: ";
                    cin >> col;
                    col = col - 1;
                    if (gameBoard.changeBoard(row, col) == false){
                        cout << "Invalid Selection, try again!" << endl;
                    }
                    gameBoard.checkWinner();
                } while (gameBoard.checkWinner() == false);
                if (gameBoard.checkWinner() == true){
                    cout << "Player " << gameBoard.printPlayer() << " wins!" << endl;
                }


            }
        } while (selection != 2);


        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

}
```

EDIT: I have changed my stupid errors now, but I still would not change the player to 2 when there is no winner. Here is my current code for that function:

```
bool TicTacToe::checkWinner(){
    if (gameBoard[0][0] && gameBoard[1][0] && gameBoard[2][0] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0][1] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][1] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0][2] && gameBoard[1][2] && gameBoard[2][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    /*********************************/
    else if (gameBoard[0][0] && gameBoard[0][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[1][0] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[1][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[2][1] && gameBoard[2][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    /*********************************/
    else if (gameBoard[0][0] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][2] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0][2] && gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][0] == playerTurn){
        return true;
    }

    /*********************************/
    else{
        if (playerTurn == 1){
            playerTurn = 2;
        }
        else{
            playerTurn = 1;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you assign using `=` here: `gameBoard[i][j] = 0;`, but didn't do it here: `playerTurn == 2;`?

Comment: That fixed one problem, but not the player change when checkWinner is called.

Comment: `checkWinner` is crying out for for loops!

Comment: Your new `checkWinner` contains some bugs. Try thinking what will happen when `gameBoard[0][0] = 1, gameBoard[1][0] = 1, gameBoard[2][0] = 2, playerTurn = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign using `==` operator (unless you use operator overload).

Use `=` operator instead to assign (update values).

Comment: Ok, thank you, this partially works now. I still cannot changed playerTurn to 2 when checkWinner is called and there is no winner. Here is that function code now:

Comment: You call `gameBoard.checkWinner()` twice at the end of the loop, and it makes `playerTurn` 2 then 1 again. `checkWinner()` should do only checking if there is a winner and changing `playerTurn` should be done in another function.

Comment: Moreover, `TicTacToe::printPlayer()` doesn't print the player and has bad function name.